# Issues in saving 'datetime' values in the database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I am working on a simple program where a customer can place many orders(i.e 'customer' has_many :orders & 'order' belongs_to :customer)

I have a form where it accepts customer name and order date:
new.html.erb

```
<h1>New order</h1>

<%= form_tag  orders_path, method: 'post' do %>
<div class="field">
    <%= label_tag  'customer_name' %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :customer_name,params[:customer_name] %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag 'order_date' %><br />
    <%= datetime_select :order_date, params[:order_date] %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "create" %>
  </div>

 <% end %>
```

The corresponding method in the controller looks like this:

```
def create
@customer= Customer.find_by_name(params[:customer_name])
@order = @customer.orders.new(:order_date => params[:order_date])

respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My question is, the params[:order_date] is a hash, I want to send it to the database as a 'datetime' value. I tried some combinations by declaring another variable of type "DateTime"  and then passing it to the database but it simply wont work.What is the solution?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
 date = DateTime.strptime("#{params['order_date']['(1i)']}-#{params['order_date']['(2i)']}-#{params['order_date']['(3i)']}T#{params['order_date']['(4i)']}:#{params['order_date']['(5i)']}", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```